# What happens to baggage transfer in non-connecting international flight?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, international-travel

I have flight from Luanda to Cape Town by TAAG Airlines.
It reaches at 1.30 pm.

I have another flight at 11.00 pm from Cape Town to Mauritius by Air Mauritius. Different PNR.

How will the baggage get transferred?

If I need to collect baggage and recheck in, I need to pass through Immigration, but I do not have any visa for Cape Town.

What happens to my baggage and how I will collect it?

Comment: Are you an Angolan passport holder? If so I believe you don't need a visa to enter SA as long as you have proof of onwards travel.

Comment: No I am not. and I donot want to enter SA. I am curious about the bags how those will get delviered to MRU or otherwise. I can wait at the airport for the next flight

Answer (score 6):

[I am assuming that you need a visa to enter South Africa, and aren't exempt based on your nationality.]

It is quite likely that you will be denied boarding by TAAG at Luanda. The reason is that as far as TAAG is concerned, you are flying to South Africa. They aren't supposed to fly people to South Africa that don't have the necessary paperwork, so if you aren't eligible for entry to South Africa, you're out.

If you can convince TAAG that you are indeed just transiting in Cape Town, you still can't take (checked-in) luggage. The reason is that you would indeed need to pass immigration, collect it, and recheck it. You also need to check how exactly South Africa's transit visa exemption policy is phrased (and interpreted) to see whether it covers self-transfer. Finally, depending how airports are set-up, there can be other obstructions to just staying airside while not formally having a connecting ticket.

Overall, self-connections via airports you don't have the paperwork for are a bad idea. You probably should either rebook your flights or get a visa for South Africa.

Comment: If your return itinerary is just a mirror of the mentioned you'll also have to convince Air Mauritius that you're only transiting in SA, else they'll deny you boarding on Mauritius. As you can't really know if you'll be succesful in that endeavour beforehand I wouldn't recommend trying.